# Allow a web designer to modify DNS without letting them transfer the domain?

Tags: domains, dns

We are in the process of having a web designer create a new website for us, but I don't want to give access to the control panel for the domain names (and have no way to limit it, it seems), while at the same time I don't want to be the go between guy for editing the settings.

Is there a way or a service for me to point the domains at a 3rd party DNS system, that I can then give access for the web designer, without worrying that he can find my personal info or try and transfer my domain out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an account with a DNS hosting company such as [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/pricing/dns-services/) (paid service, from $29.95/year).

With a DNS hosting account, you could then:

1. Set up your domains at DNS Made Easy (which they explain in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s-Et_Aqv2w&feature=BFa&list=PLE33E66331CADA357&lf=BFp)).
2. Log in to the control panel where you purchased the domain, then point your domains to use the DNS Made Easy nameservers (which they provide when you set up each domain).
3. Provide your web designer with the login information for DNS Made Easy.

This will give your designer full control of the domain settings, without allowing them to transfer, cancel, or otherwise take control of domain ownership. It will also improve your domain resolution speed a little, which can have an affect on perceived page load time.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an account with a [Cloud Flare](http://www.cloudflare.com/) (Free service, $0.00/year).

With a DNS hosting account, you could then:

Set up your domains at Cloud Flare.

Log in to the control panel where you purchased the domain, then point your domains to use the Cloud Flare nameservers

Provide your web designer with the login information for Cloud Flare.

This will give your designer full control of the domain settings, without allowing them to transfer, cancel, or otherwise take control of domain ownership. It will also improve your domain resolution speed a little, which can have an affect on perceived page load time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on a "standard host" FTP only access would do it, but you might have to set some server options from the control panel if the developer requires them.

Answer (score 0):

> Allow a web designer to modify DNS without letting them transfer the domain?

You do NOT have to transfer the domain in order to set your domains's DNS in a way that shows your new site, even if your new sites in on a server managed by the webdesigner.
This is true as long as the vendor who sold you the domain gives you control over the domain DNS records (usually it's a simple control panel that shows a list of text boxes in a form that you could modify).

> while at the same time I don't want to be the go between guy for
>   editing the settings.

The DNS has to be set once, and then there will probably no reason to modify it for the next years. So you could offer yourself to be the go between guy for editing settings, it's an opration that will take you less than 5 minutes.